# Backflip in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, hover, internet-explorer-11

I am not sure what causes this in IE11, soon as I rollover it flickers and shows the backside and then hides. Please have a look at the following jsFiddle:

```
 .front,
 .back{
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
    transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
    -o-transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
    transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
    transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1), -webkit-          transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 280px;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/st98q3x8/

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flip_container {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.front,
.back {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  -o-transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  .2,
  1);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 280px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.back {
  background: #cedce7;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #cedce7 0%, #596a72 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, #cedce7 0%, #596a72 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #cedce7 0%, #596a72 100%);
}

.front:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  opacity: .6;
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.flip_container:hover .front,
.flip_container:hover .back {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  -o-transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1), -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
  backface-visibility: visible;
}

.back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.inner {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateZ(60px) scale(0.94);
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateZ(60px) scale(0.94);
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-perspective: inherit;
  perspective: inherit;
  z-index: 2;
}

.flip_container .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip_container .front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
  backface-visibility: visible;
}

.flip_container:hover .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
  backface-visibility: visible;
}

.flip_container:hover .front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
  backface-visibility: visible;
}

.front .inner p {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  position: relative;
}

.front .inner p:after {
  content: '';
  width: 4rem;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #C6D4DF;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: -.75rem;
}

.front .inner span {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  font-weight: 300;
}

.back .inner {
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <div class="flip_container">
    <div class="front" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/500/500/); background:#5555;">
      <div class="inner">
        <p>Diligord</p>
        <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <div class="inner">
        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You forgot to make

```
-webkit-backface-visibility:visible;
          backface-visibility: visible;
```

when it is actually visible

Comment: thanks.. but the problem is soon, as you rollover it shows the back immediately and then flips: https://jsfiddle.net/st98q3x8/3/

Comment: Nope i checked mine its now correct also opened your jsfiddle in IE and its working perfect no flicker

Comment: Please have a look at this image:https://preview.ibb.co/b5VxGR/flip.png
soon as I rollover. there is no flicker, however it suddenly shows the backside and then flips..

Comment: oh yeah i guess IE is not much compatible with backface yeah i observed it during implementation but thought atleast the flixer stop and if it is too quick it wont be visible